# Chain multiple awk commands and shell scripts in sequence

Tags: shell, awk

I have written an awk/shell script to process an input xml file and output another xml file with the desired elements. While this script works, I would like to simplify it so that I do not use any temporary files and instead pipe the output between commands. 
Here's the script.

```
#extract elements
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[<|>]"} /(elementname).*$/{matchingstring=$0}
{ printf "%s\n", matchingstring}'   input.xml > tmp.xml

#sort, uniq, append closing tag (/>) 
for i in `cat tmp.xml | awk '{print $2}' |sort | uniq `; do grep -m 1  $i tmp.xml; 
done | sort -r  | sed "s/>$/\/>/" > tmp2.xml

# Append xml header and root element
awk 'BEGIN { 
FS="[<|>]"} 
NR==1{
    print "<?xml version=\"1\.0\" encoding=\"UTF\-8\"?>"
    print "<listofelements>"
};
{ printf "%s\n", $0 }
END {   print "</listifelements>";}' tmp2.xml > final.xml
```

Any inputs would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you give any sample input and output and also expalin what you are tyring to do in "#sort, uniq, append closing tag (/>) "

Comment: In the sort, uniq section, I am simply sorting by the xml element names, and getting the unique list of elements, since there are several duplicates after extraction. Here's an example of the input after the first step -

Comment: <element propa="val1" propb="val11" propc="val111_incl_spaces"> <element propa="val1" propb="val11" propc="val111_incl_spaces"> <element propa="val1" propb="val11" propc="val111_incl_spaces"> <element propa="val1" propb="val11" propc="val111_incl_spaces"> <element propa="val2" propb="val22" propc="val222_incl_spaces"> <element propa="val2" propb="val22" propc="val222_incl_spaces"> and so on. I need to get a distinct set of these elements by propa. (that's the key, the other attribs do not need to be checked for uniqueness). Sorry abt the formatting. Not sure how to format code in this section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the improvements would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[<|>]"} /(elementname).*$/{matchingstring=$0}
{ printf "%s\n", matchingstring}'   input.xml > tmp.xml
```

Can be replaced with :

```
awk '/(elementname).*$/' input.xml > tmp.xml
```

And also this below:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
FS="[<|>]"} 
NR==1{
    print "<?xml version=\"1\.0\" encoding=\"UTF\-8\"?>"
    print "<listofelements>"
};
{ printf "%s\n", $0 }
END {   print "</listifelements>";}' tmp2.xml > final.xml
```

Can be changed to :

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
print "<?xml version=\"1\.0\" encoding=\"UTF\-8\"?>";
print "<listofelements>"} 
END {print "</listifelements>";}1' tmp2.xml > final.xml
```

Comment: How is this different from `grep elementname input.xml`?

Comment: The first one, its not different. The second one is different in the sence that it will add a header and trailor to the file

Comment: Thanks, that's much simpler. Is there anyway I can avoid using temp files and use pipe between these ?